Unexpected top margin in scroll view when a Map is present in the content
I have a problem understanding why, when I add a Map to my ScrollView, the element (in this case, Color.red) does not overlap with the navigation as shown in the picture. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? The problem occurs when the view has a navigationTitle and only happens with the Map.
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                Color.red
                    .padding(.top, -200)
                    .frame(height: 200)
                
                Map().frame(minHeight: 300) // comment this line 
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}



UPDATE:
I found a solution but it requires using UIViewControllerRepresentable and the old MKMapView. Does anyone know why this is happening and why I can't use Apple's new approach in this case?
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                Color.red
                    .padding(.top, -200)
                    .frame(height: 200)
                
                MapView().frame(minHeight: 300) // comment this line
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

private typealias ViewControllerRepresentable = UIViewControllerRepresentable

struct MapView: ViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias ViewController = UIViewController

    class Controller: ViewController {
        var mapView: MKMapView {
            guard let tempView = view as? MKMapView else {
                fatalError("View could not be cast as MapView.")
            }
            return tempView
        }

        override func loadView() {
            let mapView = MKMapView()
            view = mapView

        }
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> Controller {
        Controller()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: Controller, context: Context) {
        update(controller: controller)
    }

    func update(controller: Controller) {
    }
}


Is this any closer?
**** EDIT ****
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Image("example")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(height: 400)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    Spacer()
                }
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    Map().frame(minHeight: 300)
                }
                .navigationTitle("Title")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

**** EDIT ****
The nearest I could get to what you seem to be looking for is this.
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    Color.red
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    
                    Map().frame(minHeight: 300)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
            .toolbarBackground(.red, for: .navigationBar) // <-- see here
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

The negative padding for the red is no longer required and the fill works with scrolling. BUT you will see that a faint line at the bottom of the navigation bar is visible and I don't know how to make that disappear. I haven't tested this extensively so you might run into some other problems too. Hope this helps and good luck.

Unfortunately, this is still not what I'm looking for. Your solution is decent but it only works with color. If I wanted to have a picture or another view, it would be separate.

Ah, okay, yes you're right. As a last resort I've edited the answer with some cludgy, ugly code. Is that closer to the desired result?

Thanks for replay :) Close but not enough :(.  I didn't mention this in the post, but this way I lose the ability to show ToolBarItems and when I scroll up, there's no background for the title, which also looks bad.
